# Two-dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Just a very small question... I seem to run into too much complexity here: I have to realize an index-structure like {42, someString}. I tried:

```
Object entry[][] = new Object[1][1];
ArrayList<Object> my_list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

However that looks really strange. Isn't there a better much simpler solution to just store some Integer and a String? I need to perfrom search for the Strings and return the Integer... so I thought Collections and ArrayLists are good friends in the Java API.

Comment: the problem with these questions that they have a nice general title like 'multidimensional', sounding like 'n-dimensional', and then ask about something else like '2-dimensional' which is usually far much more specific.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Solution: use a Map

Uhm, do you perhaps need a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("Some String", 42);
// or, more correctly:
map.put("Some String", Integer.valueOf(42));
```

You can search it using

```
Integer result = map.get("Some String");
```

**Reference:** [Sun Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial) > [Collection Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections) > [Interfaces](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces) > [The Map Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

---

### Fixing the OP's Code

BTW, the code in the question is flawed. Here's how you would do it if you wanted to use a List of object arrays (which you shouldn't):

```
// single dimension, not multi-dimension
Object[] entry = new Object[]{"Some String",Integer.valueOf(42)};
// use interface as variable, not implementation type
// generic type is object array, not object
List<Object[]> myList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
// add array to list
myList.add(entry);
```

Now you could search like this:

```
for(final Object[] candidate : myList){
    if("Some String".equals(candidate[0])){
        System.out.println("Result: " + candidate[1]);
        break;
    }
}
```

However, this is just for reference, don't do it this way. The Collections Framework contains solutions for almost all standard cases. Use a Map.

Comment: +1 except the key-value types should be the other way round for what the OP is asking -- to search by string.

Comment: @casablanca true, changed my answer

Comment: what about an actual n-dimensional ArrayList?

Answer (score 2):

Make a tuple class

```
 public Class IntegerStringTuple {
    private Integer number;
    private String string;

    //setters and getters etc.
 }
```

Comment: Nice idea (+1), but [`Map.Entry<K,V>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is pretty much equivalent to this and it's built into all map implementations

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you should use a Map.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

map.put(42, "someString");
String str = map.get(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a HashMap

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("foo",42);
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use a map?

```
Map<String,Object>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Maps are used to store key value pairs.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Map may not be used instead of an ArrayList when you require the order to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList();
arr2.add(1);
arr2.add(2);
arr2.add(3);
arr1.add(arr2);

for(int i=0;i<arr1.size();i++){
    System.out.println("i:"+arr1.get(i));

    for(int j=0;j<((ArrayList)arr1.get(i)).size();j++){
    System.out.println("j:"+((ArrayList)arr1.get(i)).get(j));
    }
}
```

output: i:[1, 2, 3]

```
j:1
j:2
j:3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    ArrayList<String> lcname = new ArrayList<String>();
                    lcname.add(cname);
                    
                    ArrayList<String> lsize = new ArrayList<String>();
                    lsize.add(size);

                    Dictionary dictionary = new Hashtable();

                    Hashtable<String, ArrayList<ArrayList>> hashtable = 
                    new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<ArrayList>>();

                    hashtable.put(fname, new ArrayList<>());

                    hashtable.get(fname).add(lcname);
                    hashtable.get(fname).add(lsize);

                    System.out.println(hashtable);
```

Here is the code for dictionaries of list(list).
**OUTPUT**

```
{file name=[[column name], [size]]}
```